# Create form to add selected records to specific table, instead of dropdown list, one by one

Tags: database, forms, selection

I m trying to create a database from the lab im working.
How can i create a selection form to add records to a table (ex by ticking a name) and **not adding row by row**, with drop downlist.
The Table Orders has many exams(selection)- combined with the exam results.
**I ve tried to use an append query to add records, but  they were not liked to the order id**. 
*Ex: I have created a button running the append query to add one of the exams, it is added but it is not linked to the order id.( i could make appends for every exam)

Thank you, i will really appriciate your help!!!!!
[DB relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMsQu.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please provide an example of what you have tried and exactly where you are stuck.  In the mean time, while waiting for this, your question may be closed but is likely to be re-opened if this information is provided.

Comment: Mr  Travers. I ve tried to use an append query but it didnt link the exams with the order id. 2) I couldnt greate a query with selection field that adds selected records to the selected order. I m new and i dont know to add this informatio to the question (is there an edit option?) Thank you for the information! With respect A.Athansiadis.

Comment: It is a good idea to edit your question to show us your code, what you have tried so far, and what you think the problem is.

Comment: Mr Travers i ve tried so many things... and my my access knolege isnt at top level so i refered to this site for help. Im using only access sortcuts from menu.All i do is based on the relation table at the link and access form , query and report menu.